# VueJs Async loading templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I Am building my first VueJs App and I want to asynchronous load my template. In our framework we have our templates stored in a database, that's why. 
It is working until I have some nested dom-elements in my template without any data bound to it. So my my Vuejs is like:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    finish: false,
    template: null
  },
  render: function(createElement) {
    if (!this.template) {
      return createElement('div', 'loading...');
    } else {
      return this.template();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    var self = this;
    $.post('myUrl', {foo:'bar'}, function(response){
      var tpl = response.data.template;
      self.template = Vue.compile(tpl).render;
    })
  }
})
```

This is working when my template is like:

```
<div v-show="!finish">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

But when it's like this:

```
<div v-show="!finish">
  <p>
    <span>Test</span>    
  </p>
</div>
```

I get

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of
>   undefined" (found in < Root >)

But when it's like this:

```
<div v-show="!finish">
  <p v-show="!finish">
    <span>Test</span>    
  </p>
</div>
```

It's working again.

Can anyone explain what is happening here? And is this the right way to do it or should I do it an other way?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you should try `v-if` instead of `v-show`. What `v-show` does is changing `display` property, vue is trying to render the element anyway.

[docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show)